# Magento: Change default product image with PNG

Tags: magento

In order to replace default product image in Magento, we have to replace images in this folder:

`skin\frontend\mytheme\default\images\catalog\product\placeholder`

There are 3 files:

- image.jpg
- small_image.jpg
- thumbnail.jpg

I need to replace those files with PNG. Where is the code that I can change the `.jpg` part?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the admin, under System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders, you can upload any file you want.

Comment: Do you know where the values is stored in database? I'm going to create script file.

Comment: Okay I've found it, in `core_config_data` table. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just do add information to the reply - the images are stored originally in the path: bdebela/skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder.

Names and sizes:

- image.jpg (262 x 262)
- small_image.jpg (125 x 135)
- thumbnail.jpg (50 x    50)

Comment: Hi, good info. But the small_image is also square (with 135x135). Probably a typo. Good thing you posted where they reside so I could check.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded placeholder images from admin but still not showing. I have cleared cache from backend, deleted /media/catalog/product/cache folder with no luck.

Finally, I fixed it by copying my new placeholders at **skin/frontend/default/MY_THEME/images/catalog/product/placeholder**.

where MY_THEME is my currently active theme.